# Update Gnome to latest 3.32 on Ubuntu 18.04 without upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, gnome

Title says it. How can I upgrade while staying on LTS ?

Comment: Two problems: 1) Gnome 3.32 has not yet been packaged for either Debian nor Ubuntu. 2) Replacing 3.28 packages with 3.32 won't keep you on the LTS at all, but will instead create a difficult-to-maintain Frankensystem. Some folks may create a 3.32 PPA sometime in the future, and you will get your Gnome support from them when they do.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME (and previously, Unity) versions on Ubuntu LTS (and even non-LTS) typically stick to whatever version they were at release, with only security updates applied. There will also hardly ever be a PPA for a newer GNOME version because of the sheer amount of work involved in building it and maintaining it for each new GNOME version.
The only viable option to use GNOME 3.32 (or newer) on Ubuntu is to update to 19.04 or newer as it becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use updated GNOME desktop apps (so excluding system ones like Shell) on any system on which it is possible to install [flatpak](https://flatpak.org).

You can obtain stable versions (3.34) through [flathub](https://flathub.org) and last development versions through [gnome-nightly](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nightly) repos.